# How can I resolve the error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DataWarehouse.AS'" in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I launched good old Visual Studio 2017 today to create a new Integration Services project/package. When attempting to add a new target destination (OLE DB connection), upon selecting the drop down menu for the Table/View, I was greeted with an exciting message:

> Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager
> 'MyFancyConnection.Server'.
>
> Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.DataWarehouse.AS' or one of its dependencies. The system
> cannot find the file specified.

I tried upgrading my local SQL Server 2017 to the latest CU16, this did not resolve the issue.

How can I resuscitate my Visual Studio installation?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to defeat the error by uninstalling these two extensions for Visual Studio:

- Microsoft Reporting Services Projects
- Microsoft Analysis Services Projects

Then I reinstalled the [latest SSDT for VS 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017).

On installation, I chose all 3 options (Analysis Services, Integration Services, Reporting Services). Although I would bet the only requirement to solve the problem would be AS as the original error referenced AS specifically.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the below:

**Solution:**
Go to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects and install the latest version, it has a fix in there to resolve this issue.

**Reference:** https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/745991/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftdatawareh.html

A fix for this issue has been internally implemented and is being prepared for release. We’ll update you once it becomes available for download. For now, please install latest SSAS from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects to work around the issue. Sorry for any inconvenience.